# Rewrite code from jquery to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload

Inside my widget I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[rel!=ext]').click(function() { window.onbeforeunload = null; });
    $('form').submit(function() { window.onbeforeunload = null; });
});
```

I've put this code in many webpages. My problem is that not all my webpages run jQuery so I need a JavaScript solution.

What will this look like in JavaScript code?

**UPDATE:**

```
function showWidget(www){

  var content = '<iframe src="'+www+'" style="border:0px #FFFFFF none; position: fixed;left: 0px;width: 300px; height:100%; top: 30%;z-index: 9999999;" name="myiFrame" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe><a style="display:none;" href="http://bedbids.com" rel="ext">BedBids</a>';

var newNode = document.createElement("DIV");  
newNode.innerHTML = content;
document.body.appendChild(newNode); 


window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        return "You're leaving the site.";
    };
   window.onload = function() {
   [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('a[rel!="ext"]')).forEach(function(a) {
       a.onclick = function() {
           window.onbeforeunload = null;
       };
   });
   [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('form')).forEach(function(form) {
       form.onsubmit = function() {
           window.onbeforeunload = null;
       };
   });
};

}
```

Comment: Try removing window.onload if function is executed when DOM is ready.

Comment: I remove it, but its not a solution

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work:

```
window.onload = function() {
   [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('a[rel!=ext]')).forEach(function(a) {
       a.onclick = function() {
           window.onbeforeunload = null;
       };
   });
   [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('form')).forEach(function(form) {
       form.onsubmit = function() {
           window.onbeforeunload = null;
       };
   });
};
```

Comment: I get: Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': 'a[rel!=ext]' is not a valid selector.

Comment: dont work like jquery, this code when click on some internal or external link again show message

Comment: I update my question so you can see what is the problem exactly... problem is becouse when I want to submit some form, or click on some internal - external link again I see message You're leaving the site. I needd to show this message only on user leaving